# How do I query for orders that were completed between two dates?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, datetime

I am attempting to get orders that were completed between two dates and the "before" and "after" criteria parameters don't seem to work. Perhaps I am using the wrong syntax? Example of how I am using them:

```
.after('2017-06-02 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I figured it out by doing this:

```
.dateOrdered('and', '>=' ~ startDate, '<=' ~ endDate)
```

Comment: If you want to include orders that were completed _on_ the end date, you can do `endDate|date_modify('+1 day')` :)

Comment: Does it not take the time portion into account in the parameter? For end dates, I am passing strings like "2017-06-22 23:59:59".

Comment: It does take the time into account, but only when you provide one – what you’re currently not doing! ;) `'>=' ~ startDate` returns a string ">=2017-06-02". You’d need to explicitly format the output using the `date` filter, e.g. `'>=' ~ startDate|date('c')` which would then output something like ">=2017-06-02T08:26+0800". If you prepend a `date_modify` filter you can do all sort of useful date and time calculations, see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: Sorry @Ben, I just noticed that I assumed `startDate` is a DateTime object in your code, which may not be the case at all.

Comment: We are getting the expected results now so I think we're all set. Thanks for the help!